# My app is terminating with this error. Any ideas?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tabbarcontroller

```
2012-05-08 21:33:34.279 Passwordapp[384:fb03] Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named Role
2012-05-08 21:33:34.292 Passwordapp[384:fb03] There's stuff in the database so skipping the import of default data
2012-05-08 21:33:34.293 Passwordapp[384:fb03] -[LoginViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7d750
2012-05-08 21:33:34.301 Passwordapp[384:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7d750'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1359022 0x1742cd6 0x135acbd 0x12bfed0 0x12bfcb2 0x2db6 0x390386 0x391274 0x3a0183 0x3a0c38 0x394634 0x1f93ef5 0x132d195 0x1291ff2 0x12908da 0x128fd84 0x128fc9b 0x390c65 0x392626 0x25cd 0x2535)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb) 


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "passconst.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL pinValidated;

@end



#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "KeychainWrapper.h"

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize pinValidated;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

// Helper method to congregate the Name and PIN fields for validation.
- (BOOL)credentialsValidated 
{
    NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
    BOOL pin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PIN_SAVED];
    if (name && pin) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)presentAlertViewForPassword 
{

    // 1
    BOOL hasPin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PIN_SAVED];

    // 2
    if (hasPin) {
        // 3
        NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is %@'s password?", user];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Password" 
                                                        message:message  
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
        // 4
        [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; // Gives us the password field
        alert.tag = kAlertTypePIN;
        // 5
        UITextField *pinField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
        pinField.delegate = self;
        pinField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        pinField.tag = kTextFieldPIN;
        [alert show];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Setup Credentials" 
                                                        message:@"Secure your Password list!"  
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
        // 6
        [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
        alert.tag = kAlertTypeSetup;
        UITextField *nameField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
        nameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        nameField.placeholder = @"Name"; // Replace the standard placeholder text with something more applicable
        nameField.delegate = self;
        nameField.tag = kTextFieldName;
        UITextField *passwordField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1]; // Capture the Password text field since there are 2 fields
        passwordField.delegate = self;
        passwordField.tag = kTextFieldPassword;
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (alertView.tag == kAlertTypePIN) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1 && self.pinValidated) { // User selected "Done"
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Loginsegue" sender:self];
            self.pinValidated = NO;
        } else { // User selected "Cancel"
            [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
        }
    } else if (alertView.tag == kAlertTypeSetup) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1 && [self credentialsValidated]) { // User selected "Done"
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Loginsegue" sender:self];
        } else { // User selected "Cancel"
            [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Text Field + Alert View Methods
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    // 1
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case kTextFieldPIN: // We go here if this is the 2nd+ time used (we've already set a PIN at Setup).
            NSLog(@"User entered PIN to validate");
            if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
                // 2
                NSUInteger fieldHash = [textField.text hash]; // Get the hash of the entered PIN, minimize contact with the real password
                // 3
                if ([KeychainWrapper compareKeychainValueForMatchingPIN:fieldHash]) { // Compare them
                    NSLog(@"** User Authenticated!!");
                    self.pinValidated = YES;
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"** Wrong Password :(");
                    self.pinValidated = NO;
                }
            }
            break;
        case kTextFieldName: // 1st part of the Setup flow.
            NSLog(@"User entered name");
            if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:textField.text forKey:USERNAME];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
            break;
        case kTextFieldPassword: // 2nd half of the Setup flow.
            NSLog(@"User entered PIN");
            if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
                NSUInteger fieldHash = [textField.text hash];
                // 4
                NSString *fieldString = [KeychainWrapper securedSHA256DigestHashForPIN:fieldHash];
                NSLog(@"** Password Hash - %@", fieldString);
                // Save PIN hash to the keychain (NEVER store the direct PIN)
                if ([KeychainWrapper createKeychainValue:fieldString forIdentifier:PIN_SAVED]) {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:PIN_SAVED];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                    NSLog(@"** Key saved successfully to Keychain!!");
                }                
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pinValidated = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

in your project you are trying to call [loginViewControllerObject viewController]; which is a navigation controller method

Comment: I am trying to load the login screen first and then call a tab controller how can I do this then